# why tesseract showing error " Unable to create ocr model using Path and language " for other language except eng?

Tags: c#, winforms, ocr, tesseract, emgucv

I m making an window application using c# using tesseract with Emgucv. everything is working fine when i use "eng" as a language for the tesseract engine but when i try to make some other .traineddata it gives me the error  " Unable to create OCR model using Path and language ". i m making .traineddata file from this website http://trainyourtesseract.com/ for the terminal font . one more thing for few hours everything worked fine but suddenly after that i was started getting the error.

Here is my code which is working fine

```
Tesseract OCRz = new Tesseract("tessdata2", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT);
```

This is the code which  is giving me error

```
Tesseract OCRz = new Tesseract("tessdata2", "Terminal", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT);
```

eng.traineddata and Terminal.traineddata both are placed in tessdata2 folder within my application

[explorer file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQxqg.png)

Thanks

Comment: no none of these helped already checked all

Comment: Tesseract OCRz = new Tesseract("tessdata2", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT);  here tessdata2 is the path of the tessdata which i placed inside my application the above code work fine .i have Terminal.traineddata file in the same folder  when i replace eng with the Terminal i got the error

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: i have just deleted the bigrams file some one mentioned somwhere to delete the cube.cnn and bigrams file once so i delete it . if there file are still there i m getting the same error

Comment: i would like to explain one thing i have just created the terminal.traineddata from the website mentioned above in the question but all other file i have just renamed from eng to terminal and add it in the folder

Comment: screen shot updated

Answer (score 1):

the error has been resolved it was nothing just changed the path

From `tessdata2`   to   `../tessdata2` and everything started working fine

Don't know the exact reason behind it but it solved my problem may this also help someone